# Can't fetch data on page load with Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

The code below should display data fetched from backend upon page load.

Instead, the data shows up only after I make some unrelated change in the code that triggers Vue page update.

Why is it not working upon page load?

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ projects }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
let projects = ref([])

const getData = () => {
  fetch('https://www.my-site.com/wp/wp-json/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(res => res.json()).then((response) => {
      projects = response
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
}

getData()
</script>
```

Comment: This is just not how suspense works. If the component was an async dependency (which it isn't since setup is not async), it could be wrapped by suspense in the parent component. In your case, you can just remove the whole suspense block and it should work.

Comment: @MoritzRingler thanks, I updated my question accordingly. The issue is still occuring though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you are overriding your ref. Assign to its `value` prop instead:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const projects = ref([]) // <---- use const to make the error impossible 

const getData = () => {
  fetch('https://www.my-site.com/wp/wp-json/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(res => res.json()).then((response) => {
      projects.value = response // <---- assign to the ref's value
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
}

getData()
</script>
```